# XML Parsing error expecting closing tag? (After adding form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Since adding a form I've suddenly recieved the follwing error:

> XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: /link>.

Even if I add closing link tags, the same error arises saying a closing head tag is required but it is there and no closing link tags were required before I adding the following form.

## edit: The error happens after clicking the add, form submission button

## SOLVED EDIT: In the first line of the submit function i used preventDefault to stop the form from submitting until my if else statement was completed. this.submit(); added at the end

HTML:

```
<form id="listForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
    <input id="listInput" class="textarea" placeholder="Add your list item here, then click submit.">
    <div id="checkboxContainer">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
//ADD LIST ITEM
$("#listForm").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if ($("#listInput").val() == "") {
        alert("Please enter the item name, then click 'Add'.");
    } else {
        listCount++;
        var input = $("#listInput").val();

        console.log("List Count: " + listCount);
        console.log(input);

        var cb = document.createElement('input');
        cb.id = 'input' + listCount;
        cb.type = 'checkbox';
        document.getElementById("checkboxContainer").appendChild(cb);


        $("#input" + listCount).text(input);

        //Store the list count
        localStorage.setItem("listCount", listCount);

        //Store the list title
        localStorage.setItem("input" + listCount, input); //"Note " + noteCount + ": " + 

        this.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Input elements dont need a closing tag right?

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying @JonBrave I've fixed it now